# Get unique values of multiple columns as a new dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Having pandas data frame `df` with at least columns C1,C2,C3 how would you get all the unique C1,C2,C3 values as a new DataFrame?

in other words, similiar to :

```
SELECT C1,C2,C3
FROM T
GROUP BY C1,C2,C3
```

Tried that

```
print df.groupby(by=['C1','C2','C3'])
```

but im getting

```
<pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x000000000769A9E8>
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I believe you need [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) if want all unique triples:

```
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['C1','C2','C3'])
```

If want use `groupby` add [`first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html):

```
df = df.groupby(by=['C1','C2','C3'], as_index=False).first()
```